# Angular - how to pass an url to ng-src in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and I am trying to make a custom directive out of this template:

```
      <img ng-hide="videoPlaying" ng-src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/{{ article.external_media[0].video_id }}/maxresdefault.jpg" class="cover">
      <youtube-video ng-if="videoPlaying" video-url="article.external_media[0].original_url" player="youtubePlayer" player-vars="playerVars" class="video"></youtube-video>
      <div ng-hide="videoPlaying" class="iframe-overlay" ng-click="playVideo(youtubePlayer)">
        <img ng-hide="videoPlaying" class="play" src="icons/play.svg"/>
        <img ng-hide="videoPlaying" class="playButton" src="icons/playRectangle.svg"/>
      </div>
```

In this case `youtube-video` is another directive, since I am using [youtube-angular-embed](https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed) package.
I am wondering how to pass an url that is in my case `{{ article.external_media[0].video_id }}` to `ng-src` for an image in my directive?
This is how far I got with my directive so far:

```
angular.module('coop.directives')
.directive('youtubePlayer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          videoPlaying: '=videoPlaying',
          playVideo = '=playVideo'
         },
        template : "<img ng-hide='videoPlaying' ng-src='http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/{{ article.external_media[0].video_id }}/maxresdefault.jpg' class='cover'><youtube-video ng-if='videoPlaying' video-url='article.external_media[0].original_url' player='player' player-vars='playerVars' class='video'></youtube-video><div ng-hide='videoPlaying' class='iframe-overlay' ng-click='playVideo(player)'><img ng-hide='videoPlaying' class='play' src='icons/play.svg'/><img ng-hide='videoPlaying' class='playButton' src='icons/playRectangle.svg'/></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        }
    };
});
```

And then in my view I am calling directive like this:

```
<youtube-player></youtube-player>
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't defined the controller in your directive, so your {{ article.external_media[0].video_id }} looks like it would be undefined

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need to set the url to ngSrc.

you can insert an extra article param to your directive and use it to create the url on the controller of the directive.

```
angular.module('coop.directives')
.directive('youtubePlayer', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      videoPlaying: '=videoPlaying',
      playVideo: '=playVideo',
      article: '='
    },
    template : "<img ng-hide='videoPlaying' ng-src='{{myUrl}}' class='cover'><youtube-video ng-if='videoPlaying' video-url='article.external_media[0].original_url' player='player' player-vars='playerVars' class='video'></youtube-video><div ng-hide='videoPlaying' class='iframe-overlay' ng-click='playVideo(player)'><img ng-hide='videoPlaying' class='play' src='icons/play.svg'/><img ng-hide='videoPlaying' class='playButton' src='icons/playRectangle.svg'/></div>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
       $scope.myUrl = 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/'+$scope.article.external_media[0].video_id+'/maxresdefault.jpg'
    }
};
```

});

so you can use your directive now as:

```
<youtube-player video-playing="video" play-video="play" article="article"></youtube-player>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  scope: {
      videoPlaying: '@videoPlaying',
      playVideo: '@playVideo'
  },
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that, I am calling my directive right, I have updated my question, but that is another directive inside this directive that I am making. I am using angular-youtube-embed and therefor I have the youtube-video directive there.

Comment: ohhhh okay gotcha. Does the rest of my answer help at all?

Comment: and what's happening? Is the directive showing up but the values just aren't taking effect?

Comment: The directive is showing up, as before, I just don't get any values for ng-src, and video-url.

Comment: Updated my answer... let me know

Comment: I have a video now, but the image overlay is gone as well as play button that I had before.

Comment: Could you post everything you have in a fiddle?

Comment: I have made a fiddle with all I have in my controller and directive here https://jsfiddle.net/n8o7m168/

Comment: You're missing the myApp and coop controller definitions. Also be sure to include angular in the external resources or I won't be able to run this

Answer (score 0):

```
scope: {
  videoPlaying: '=videoPlaying',
  playVideo: '=playVideo'
  article: '=article'
},
```

Then you can use it in your template:

```
template : "<img ng-hide='videoPlaying' ng-src='http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/{{ article.external_media[0].video_id }}/maxresdefault.jpg' class='cover'><youtube-video ng-if='videoPlaying' video-url='article.external_media[0].original_url' player='player' player-vars='playerVars' class='video'></youtube-video><div ng-hide='videoPlaying' class='iframe-overlay' ng-click='playVideo(player)'><img ng-hide='videoPlaying' class='play' src='icons/play.svg'/><img ng-hide='videoPlaying' class='playButton' src='icons/playRectangle.svg'/></div>",
```

Now in your view, you would call the directive like this:

```
<youtube-player video-playing="video" play-video="play" article="article"></youtube-player>
```

All these `video, play and article` are objects bound to your `scope` in `controller`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but nothing has changed, I still don't get anything for the iframe.